# What is occurring inside the lattice structure of metal when compression happens?

Tags: pressure, electrons, metals

I was browsing reddit and saw this [post](https://www.reddit.com/r/oddlysatisfying/comments/ddkji7/compressing_hot_metal_with_hydraulic_press/). It is a gif of a factory, with a huge press squashing a hot chunk of metal.

I'm specifically interested in the behavior that is happening after the initial press when the slag falls off. When the press starts compressing the metal, it begins shooting off what looks like to be sparks.

[image]

The only way I can think of explaining that is with the metallic bond's "sea of electrons" model.

[image]

Which when the lattice structure starts to be compressed, there is less space for the valence electrons to freely occupy, and thus a greater electromagnetic potential from neighboring electrons. This would mean that the valence electrons would have a higher possibility of being shot off in the form of sparks.

What I'm not understanding is, if the chunk of metal has had an increase in EM potential due to compression, why does that potential not force it back into it's previous position when the press is lifted? Are the valence electrons lost in the sparks enough to create equilibrium at the new pressure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

when it is being deformed in the hot press, the atoms in its lattice are being pushed past one another, and the solid metal flows like stiff taffy.

The slag on the outside is brittle, and when it exfoliates, a fresh new red-hot iron surface is exposed to air. It violently oxidizes, producing flames and sparks.

Each time the ingot is deformed more, the oxide layer covering the surface of the iron cracks and splits, exposing crevices of hot iron to the air, and in those zones, the iron oxidizes again, and shoots out tiny hot flames.

Those flames are not electric sparks.

Comment: Do you know if my explanation for the sparks might occur in a different scenario? Perhaps on a larger scale in space.

Comment: Nope, I do not.